# Allocating and constructing an object

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code that allocates and constructs an object:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <new>          

struct MyClass {
  int data;

};

int main () {

  struct MyClass *p1=new MyClass;


  return 0;
}
```

So,if i understand correctly p1 is a pointer to a memory location where a Myclass Object is stored.So if i want for this particular object to update the int data value how can i do it?

Comment: _"So if i want for this particular object to update the int data value how can i do it?"_ What about `p1->data = 42;`?

Comment: `p1->data = 42;`. And [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?r=SearchResults&s=1|836.0633) should be a priority at this point. edit: @πάνταῥεῖ I swear to God I didn't see your assignment before posting mine. It really is the answer to everything.

Comment: @WhozCraig _" I swear to God I didn't see your assignment before posting mine."_ Seems we're nerds ;-D ...

Comment: `struct MyClass *p1=new MyClass;` note that in `c++` you don't need the `struct` part of that. `MyClass *p1=new MyClass;` is sufficient.

Comment: You almost never need `new` and `delete` in modern C++. Consider them an advanced feature. If the object doesn't need to live longer than the nearest `{}` block, use an ordinary definition `MyClass obj1;`. If it does need to live longer, use `auto p1 = std::make_unique<MyClass>();` or `auto p1 = std::make_shared<MyClass>();`.

Comment: @aschepler Is p1 an object or a pointer to an object's location?

Comment: @Epitheoritis In my examples `p1` is either a `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>` or a `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>`. Both of these are class objects, which act much like raw pointers (you can do `*p1` and `p1->data`).

Answer (score 1):

Members of objects without pointers are accessed by `.` I hope you know that, members of class pointers are accessed by `->`. In your case

```
p1->data = 55
```